# What question is an open question?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What are possible definitions of the phrase "**open question**" in a given context?

In other words, if I would like to name a yet to be answered question, a question requiring more than a simple Yes or No answer, a non-personal question, or a question that invite everyone to contribute in answering, can I call it an open question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **yes**.

"*Open question*" is commonly used to describe a question which is

1. open to a variety of answers
2. open to a variety of people to answer it
3. unanswered, when in context of "an answer has yet to be found" or message boards etc where the question/topic hasn't been closed

I have yet to see a question that's non-personal being called "open", though.

Answer (score 0):

For example, whether God exists is an open question.  Whether there are extraterrestrials or not is an open question.  There are lots more.  And of course, most open questions are open for some and closed for others, :)